# In R: How to subset a large dataframe by top 5 longest runs of frequent values in 1 column?

Tags: r, run-length-encoding

I have a dataframe with 1 column. The values in this column can ONLY be "good" or "bad". I would like to find the top 5 largest runs of "bad".

I am able to use the rle(df) function to get the running length of all the "good" and "bad".

1. How do i find the 5 largest runs that attribute to ONLY "bad"?
2. How do i get the starting and ending indices of the top 5 largest runs for ONLY "bad"?

Your assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example to explain your question and show expected output based on that so that it is easier for others to help you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be `rleid`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), creating grouping column with `rleid` (generates a unique id based on adjacent non-matching elements, create the number of elements per group (`n`)  as a column, and row number also as another column ('rn'), subset the rows where 'goodbad' is "bad", `order` 'n' in decreasing order, grouped by 'grp', summarise the 'first' and 'last' row numbe, as well  as the entry for goodbad

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(goodbad)][,  n := .N, grp][ ,
   rn := .I][goodbad == 'bad'][order(-n), .(goodbad = first(goodbad), 
    n = n, start = rn[1], last = rn[.N]), .(grp)
    ][n %in% head(unique(n), 5)][, grp := NULL][]
```

---

Or we can use `rle` and other `base R` methods

```
rl <- rle(df1$goodbad)
grp <- with(rl, rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
df2 <- transform(df1, grp = grp, n = rep(rl$lengths, rl$lengths),
            rn = seq_len(nrow(df1)))
df3 <- subset(df2, goodbad == 'bad')
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(rn ~ grp, subset(df3[order(-df3$n),], 
      n %in% head(unique(n), 5)), range))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(goodbad = sample(c("good", "bad"), 100,
          replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This does work, but is there any way you can break up the code into small blocks so i can better understand what is happening...i am trying to learn as well. I dont need to run it all in memory either...if you can help with the re-write i think i should be able to understand it more easily.

Comment: @Chris I added some description

Comment: This helps. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The sort(...) function arranges things by increasing or decreasing order. The default is increasing, but you can set "decreasing = TRUE". Use ?sort for more info.

The which(...) function returns the INDEX of values that meet a logical criteria. The code below sorts the times columns of rows where the goodbad value == GOOD.

```
sort(your.df$times[which(your.df$goodbad == GOOD)])
```

If you wanted to get the top 5 you could do this:

```
top5_good <- sort(your.df$times[which(your.df$goodbad == GOOD)])[1:5]

top5_bad <- sort(your.df$times[which(your.df$goodbad == BAD)])[1:5]
```

Comment: The dataframe is already sorted. If i re-sort then all the "good" and "bad" would just group together, no?